# How do I use babel in a node CLI program?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm writing a small CLI tool in node and would like to use ES6 for that.

index.js looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

require('babel/register');
module.exports = require('./app');
```

I can easily invoke that using

```
$ node index.js --foo some --bar thing
```

In my `package.json` I declare the following:

```
  "bin": {
    "my-tool": "./index.js"
  }
```

When installing and executing this it seems that babel is not working as I am getting:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/my-tool/app.es6:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import yargs fro
                                                          ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

What is it that I am missing here?

Comment: Not sure why this happens (I can reproduce). As a quick fix, perhaps you can use `#!/usr/bin/env babel-node` instead?

Comment: I don't think babel's on-the-fly compilation works with module syntax.

Comment: Then I don't understand what it does at all: where is the difference when invoked via `node index.js` (working) and `my-tool` (not working)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The require hook is meant more for local development than for production use. Ideally you'd precompile before distributing your package. You are running into https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1889.

You'll need to explicitly tell the register hook not to ignore your application.

```
require('babel/register')({
  ignore: /node_modules\/(?!my-tool)/
});
```