# How can I use Babel for CLI program?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to write some CLI program on node using Babel. I'd seen question [How do I use babel in a node CLI program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31447120/how-do-i-use-babel-in-a-node-cli-program/31458731#31458731) and there [loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/loganfsmyth) said:

> Ideally you'd precompile before distributing your package.

Okay, now I'm using:

```
"scripts": {
    "transpile": "babel cli.js --out-file cli.es5.js",
    "prepublish": "npm run transpile",
}
```

But, I faced the problem, when Babel adds `'use strict';` line right behind `#!/usr/bin/env node` header. For example, if I have `cli.js`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

import pkg from './package'

console.log(pkg.version);
```

I'll get this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node'use strict';

var _package = require('./package');

… … …
```

And this doesn't work. When I try to run it, I always get:

```
/usr/bin/env: node'use strict';: This file or directory does'nt exist
```

How can I solved this problem?

Comment: Do you really _need_ Babel? Node supports any ES6 features included in V8: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/

Comment: This program should work on node>=0.10, so I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution from @DanPrince is perfectly acceptable but there's an alternative

**cli.js**

keep this file es5

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require("./run.es5.js");
```

**run.js**

```
// Put the contents of your existing cli.js file here,
// but this time *without* the shebang
// ...
```

Update your scripts to

```
"scripts": {
    "transpile": "babel run.js > run.es5.js",
    "prepublish": "npm run transpile",
}
```

The idea here is that the `cli.js` shim doesn't need to be tranpsiled so you can keep your shebang in that file.

`cli.js` will just load `run.es5.js` which is the babel-transpiled version of `run.js`.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I'm looking for. It seems more elegant than bash script.

Answer (score 1):

You could use another NPM script to add the shebang as the last part of your build process. It ain't pretty but it works.

```
"scripts": {
  "transpile": "babel cli.js --out-file es5.js",
  "shebang": "echo -e '#!/usr/bin/env/node\n' $(cat es5.js) > cli.es5.js",
  "prepublish": "npm run transpile && npm run shebang",
}
```

Then your original `cli.js` would become

```
import pkg from './package'

console.log(pkg.version);
```

The resulting `es5.js` file becomes

```
'use strict';

var _package = require('./package');
```

And finally, `cli.es5.js` becomes

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

var _package = require('./package');
```

This could be improved with a clean script.

```
"scripts": {
  "transpile": "babel cli.js --out-file es5.js",
  "shebang": "echo -e '#!/usr/bin/env/node\n' $(cat es5.js) > cli.es5.js",
  "clean": "rm es5.js cli.es5.js",
  "prepublish": "npm run clean && npm run transpile && npm run shebang",
}
```

Of course, this requires that you are on a system with bash (or some alternate compatible shell), however you could make it cross-platform by rewriting the build scripts to use node implementations of these commands with something like [ShellJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs).

Comment: It doesn't looks like an elegant solution, but ,yep, that should works. Thank you so much!