# babel-node fails to require jsx file in node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I know `babel-node` ignores `node_modules` by default, so I ran it three different ways to override it, all failed:

1. ran `babel-node app.js` with `.babelrc`:

   ```
   {
     "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
     "only": [
       "app",
       "node_modules/react-components"
     ]
   }
   ```

   result: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` for the required jsx node module
2. ran `babel-node app.js` with `.babelrc`:

   ```
   {
     "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
     "ignore": "node_modules\/(?!react-components)"
   }
   ```

   result: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` for the require jsx node module
3. ran `babel-node ./bin/www --ignore '/node_modules/(?!react-components)` with `.babelrc`:

   ```
   {
     "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
   }
   ```

   result:

   ```
   [project]/node_modules/babel-preset-react/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx/lib/index.js:12
       var visitor = require("babel-helper-builder-react-jsx")({
                                                              ^

   TypeError: object is not a function
   ```

---

Using the register hook with the ignore option worked correctly.

ran `node app.js` with this code in the beginning of `app.js`

```
require('babel-core/register')({
    ignore: /node_modules\/(?!react-components)/
});
```

Even though this works, I still want to know why my implementations with `babel-node` does not work. Thanks.

---

references:

- [How do I use babel in a node CLI program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31447120/how-do-i-use-babel-in-a-node-cli-program)
- [import a module from node_modules with babel but failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822593/import-a-module-from-node-modules-with-babel-but-failed)
- http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/
- http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in babel, where it ignores `only` and `ignore`.

The relevant bug is [T6726](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/3789), which has been [fixed in babel 6.14.0](https://github.com/babel/babel/releases/tag/v6.14.0).